# How to return an iterator over even numbers, given an iterator over a list of integers?

Tags: java, iterator

I was asked this question in a java interview. I am given an iterator for a list of integers. I need to write a function that returns takes this iterator as argument and returns the iterator for even numbers only. I was told, I cannot modify the original list of numbers. Hence, removing odd numbers from the list is not the solution. Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Well you basically just need to create a new Iterator that takes an existing Iterator and overwrite its hasNext and next methods. The only difficulty is that a good behaving iterator should obviously only take O(1) space, so creating a new list and using that is bad style - hence we need a bit bookkeeping. Something like the following - simplified pseudo code without error handling, assuming null as an invalid value, etc. but for a somewhat general solution - should give you the basic idea:

```
Iterator<T> it;
T next;

NewIterator(Iterator<T> it) {
    this.it = it;
    setNext();
}

void setNext() {
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        T val = it.next();
        if (validT(val)) {
            next = val;
            return;
        }
    }
    next = null; // lets assume null is invalid.
}

boolean hasNext() {
    return next != null;
}

T next() {
   T ret = next;
   setNext();
   return ret;
}
```

Comment: I think this is basically correct.  `setNext` is unbounded in time.  Therefor setNext, hasNext, and next should be syncronized.

Comment: I'm not sure that it's acceptable that the constructor already starts scanning the underlying iterator...

Comment: @Kaarel Well you can easily change that, but the only other possible place where you can do it then is in the `hasNext` call, which is imo much worse..

Answer (score 0):

```
Iterator<Integer> itr;
int cur;

OddIterator(Iterator<Integer> itr) {
    this.itr = itr;
    cur = 0;
}

public boolean hasNext() {
    if ((cur & 1) == 1) {
        return true;
    }
    while (itr != null && itr.hasNext()) {
        cur = itr.next();
        if ((cur & 1) == 1) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public int next() {
    if (!hasNext()) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
    int tmp = cur;
    cur = 0;
    return tmp;
}
```

I hope this would help you. If there're any bugs with my code. Please let me know.